# Extending styles and themes confusion

Tags: android, layout, coding-style, themes, extending

In my manifest I used to have something like this

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
     android:label="@string/app_name"
        name="Theme.NoTitleBar"...
```

and it worked great, I mean the title bar was not shown.

But now I want to customize the theme (I want to extend the default android theme)
and I created this theme

```
<style name="Theme.NoTitleBar.new_skin" parent="android:Theme">
        <item name="text_body_read">@style/text_body_read</item>
        <item name="text_body_unread">@style/text_body_unread</item>
    </style>
```

then in the manifest I set `name="Theme.NoTitleBar.new_skin"`, but the title bar is still shown.

how can I hide the title bar and still have my new custom theme ?

and one more question does adding dots '.' means extending when working with styles ?

Answer (score 2):

in your mainfest you should write something like:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
     android:label="@string/app_name"
        name="MyTheme"...
```

In your styles.xml you should write something like:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="android:Theme.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="text_body_read">@style/text_body_read</item>
        <item name="text_body_unread">@style/text_body_unread</item>
 </style>
```

Dot (.) doesn't mean extending. It means referencing a certain element (listview, textview etc.) in your theme. For example, you would have:

```
<style name="MyTheme.Widget.ListView" parent="@android:style/Widget.ListView.White">
</style>
```

to define style of your listview.

Comment: the problem is that I have name="MyTheme" in my manifest and parent="android:Theme.NoTitleBar"  in the style but I still have the title bar visible

Comment: try this:    

1. inside your theme style add:    

 <item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@style/MyTheme.WindowTitleBackground</item>

2. create a new style:
<style name="MyTheme.WindowTitleBackground" parent="android:WindowTitleBackground">    
        <item name="android:background">@null</item>
</style>

Comment: It gives me an error, it couldn't find parent="android:WindowTitleBackground, but what is the point with the background ? I need just the title bar to be hidden

Comment: it makes your title not visible.

Comment: eclipse complains about parent="android:WindowTitleBackground", it says no resource found ...

Comment: You wrote that "Dot (.) doesn't mean extending" but it actually means that in context of Themes. Please take a look here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes The quote is following: "You can also inherit styles (...) with a dot notation, instead of using the parent attribute."